# How to center modal in screen?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have bootstrap modal when fire the modal it show on top center of page even when scroll page content down I can't see the modal dialog because its on top of page how can center it on screen.

```
.modal{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;z- index:1050;display:none;overflow:hidden;outline:0}
```

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically

Answer (score 1):

Update your HTML with the following code

```
.modal
 .modal-dialog.modal-dialog-centered
```

Or remove this style from modal element

```
{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;z- index:1050;display:none;overflow:hidden;outline:0}
```

And update your CSS with the following code

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Comment: Did you try the two solutions ?

Comment: thank you > yes i tried . nothing make it center screen

Answer (score 0):

I usually display a container div with grid, and place my modal in it:

```css
.containerDiv {
    display: grid;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    place-items: center;
    background: transparent;

}
```

Comment: could you provide the output?